# Bootstrap modal width on a phone opens to small (width)

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am working on a page which is using Bootstrap 4 and uses a modal window to display some information. It works fine on a desktop/laptop/tablet but when I test it out on a phone the modal opens but the width is very narrow. Is there something I should be looking at to increase the width of the modal when displayed on phones.

Code example of modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="workwith">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      
      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">WTitle</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
    <ul>
      <li class="li-item"><a href="https://xxxx" target="_blank">xxxx</a></li>
      <li class="li-item"><a href="https://xxxx" target="_blank">xxxx</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="pic_frame_right">
    <img src="img/pics/three_pis2.png"> </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Bootstrap nav

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm sticky-top"> 

   <button class="navbar-toggler"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu1"> 
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#workwith">Facilities</a> </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

just found the cause, I had the css modal-lg set to a max-width=60%